# How to get the processed results from dramatiq python?

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, dramatiq

```
import dramatiq
from dramatiq.brokers.redis import RedisBroker
from dramatiq.results import Results
from dramatiq.results.backends import RedisBackend

broker = RedisBroker(host="127.0.0.1", port=6379)
broker.declare_queue("default")
dramatiq.set_broker(broker)
# backend = RedisBackend()
# broker.add_middleware(Results(backend=backend))

@dramatiq.actor()
def print_words(text):
        print('This is ' + text)

print_words('sync')
a = print_words.send('async')
a.get_results()
```

I was checking alternatives to celery and found Dramatiq. I'm just getting started with dramatiq and I'm unable to retrieve results. I even tried setting the backend and 'save_results' to True. I'm always getting this `AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'get_results'`

Any idea on how to get the result?

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right track with adding a result backend. The way to instruct an actor to store results is `store_results=True`, not `save_results` and the method to retrieve results is [`get_result()`](https://dramatiq.io/reference.html#dramatiq.results.Results), not `get_results`.

Comment: I made these changes and I’m getting dramatiq.results.errors.ResultMissing’. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Are you returning a value from the actor? The example code in your question does not so that's probably the problem.

Comment: Yeah. I tried with the example.py provided in your github repo and still I get the error. `dramatiq.results.errors.ResultMissing: count_words('https://www.crash.net')` . The count is getting printed in the terminal running the command `dramatiq example` but I can't return the result.

Answer (score 0):

When you run [get_result()](https://dramatiq.io/reference.html#dramatiq.Message.get_result) with `block=False`, you should wait the worker set result ready, like this:

```py
while True:
    try:
        res = a.get_result(backend=backend)
        break
    except dramatiq.results.errors.ResultMissing:
        # do something like retry N times.
        time.sleep(1)
print(res)
```